# Jquery - only show one element for each response - JSON

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list where I output each row from a mysql table, and in this list I have a search function where you can search after different keywords.

So first I have a jquery function that outputs each item in my mysql table, and another function that triggers on search field on each input.

My code is like this:

```
('.rbmSearchFeild').on('input', 
    function(){
        var rbCustomSearch = $('.rbmSearchFeild').val();
        if( !$(this).val() ) {
            $('.rbItem li.non').show();
            $('.rbItem li.search').remove();
        } else {
            $.getJSON('link to my custom search function?searchtag='+rbCustomSearch, function(data) {
                $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                    $('.rbItem li.non').hide();
                    $('.rbItem').append('<li class="'+value.name+' search"><img src="'+value.picture+'" /><span>'+value.name+'</span></li>');
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

So if the search field is empty it will show the entire list, but start typing it will hide these items and only show the search items. But with my code now, it shows the same item over and over again for each search letter i put in.

How can I only output the item one time?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You just want to show one result? them why are you looping through data?

Comment: Let say I type in 'T'- this will give me 5 different items. And then if I type in 'TA' and still 5 different it will then show 10, because of the last time it showed the results.

Comment: You want it to show just the 5 items next time, right?

Comment: $('.rbItem').empty() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `else` part of your code as follows:

```
else {
        $.getJSON('link to my custom search function?searchtag='+rbCustomSearch, function(data) {
           $('.rbItem').empty(); // empty the previous results
            $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                $('.rbItem li.non').hide();
                $('.rbItem').append('<li class="'+value.name+' search"><img src="'+value.picture+'" /><span>'+value.name+'</span></li>');
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Did not think of that! :) Now I only need to check if two element has the same class, dynamic.